# Calculating vif in faraway: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(828L, 828L, 828L, 828L, : replacement has 4928 rows, data has 704

Tags: r

Hi there I am trying to calculate variance inflation factors (vif) in the `faraway` package. I am very new to R, so please bear with me.

Here is my dataset:

```
str(SMB)
'data.frame':   1266 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ X2011        : int  550 547 543 546 544 548 545 549 42 49 ...
 $ CatchID      : num  0.5 0.2 0.6 0.1 0.7 0.3 0.8 0.4 1 2 ...
 $ StomachID    : int  5 2 6 1 7 3 8 4 NA 304 ...
 $ Date         : Factor w/ 68 levels "2011-06-18","2011-06-22",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 43 43 ...
 $ Lake         : Factor w/ 9 levels "Beaver Lake",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 ...
 $ Year         : int  2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2012 2012 ...
 $ Site.        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Set.         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 ...
 $ SampleMeth   : Factor w/ 3 levels "GN","MN","SG": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Habitat      : Factor w/ 6 levels "","BARE","MIX",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 6 ...
 $ DegDays      : int  209 209 209 209 209 209 209 209 NA 155 ...
 $ Weight.g.    : num  1093 635 1583 607 1651 ...
 $ Length.mm.   : num  453 360 480 345 480 373 482 400 195 269 ...
 $ CondFactor   : Factor w/ 147 levels "#DIV/0!","0",..: 47 65 72 77 78 79 82 88 84 61 ...
 $ Age          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2.3 ...
 $ Species      : Factor w/ 6 levels "CT","KO","PMB",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Fish..Set    : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 ...
 $ SppDiv.Set   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Fish..Spp.Set: int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 1 3 ...
 $ Soak.Hrs.    : num  1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 2.02 2.02 ...
 $ CT_CPUE      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RB_CPUE      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SMB_CPUE     : num  6.67 6.67 6.67 6.67 6.67 6.67 6.67 6.67 0.5 1.49 ...
 $ KOK.CPUE     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ YP.CPUE      : Factor w/ 21 levels "#DIV/0!","0",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ PMB.CPUE     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TotalEn      : num  33894 892 32386 1901 32764 ...
 $ PreyDiv      : int  1 2 1 5 1 3 1 2 NA 1 ...
 $ CrayPresent  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CrayAbund    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

vif(SMB[,-30]) or vif(SMB)
```

When I try to calculate vif, I get this error:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(47L, 58L, 161L, 147L,
>   :    replacement has 5180 rows, data has 185

The values and replacement rows are different each time. Does anyone have any idea what I should do?

Thank you,
dez

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have used `car::vif(model)` in the past and it takes a model rather than a dataframe. You should check that the same isn't true for the `faraway` package.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. One of my variables was categorical and vifs can only be calculated for continuous data. The  faraway package works with dataframes, which is very helpful for raw exploration in my case.  Thank you for your input everyone!

My solution was to create a new vector with only necessary continuous variables (cutting out the columns I didn't need)

Comment: SMB5 <- (SMB[,-c(1:9, 11:19, 23:28)]) # create vector with selected     variables to eliminate categorical data.

#check for colinearity with vif

    library(faraway)
    print (vif(SMB5)) 

    DegDays   CT_CPUE   RB_CPUE  SMB_CPUE CrayAbund       row 
    1.169096  1.249445  1.275851  1.149355  1.090310  1.231609

Comment: I find the statement that  "vifs can only be calculated for continuous data" highly dubious.